# listBox sort by week and year

Tags: c#, sql

I have these values in a listBox:

```
Week 02 [2020]
Week 03 [2020]
Week 36 [2019]
Week 40 [2019]
Week 47 [2019]
Week 52 [2019]
```

And I want to order it in Descending (numerically only) order.

```
Week 03 [2020]
Week 02 [2020]
Week 52 [2019]
Week 51 [2019]
Week 50 [2019]
Week 49 [2019]
```

How can I do this, or even how can I get the data ordered like this from SQL? I already tried to get it from SQL (ORDER BY) but the result is almost the same...

Thank you!

Comment: you tried order by Week desc, year desc?

Comment: What is format of this data?

Comment: How? It's a varchar field "Week xx [xxxx]" in DB, so I can't order by a week or a year only... well not with my knowledge!!!

Comment: This is a classical example of breaking 1NF in database modelling, a single attribute should contain a single piece of information. The correct approach here, if done early enough, would have been to break up the field so that you have either the date in an attribute and can work out the year and week number from that, or the year and week number in separate attributes, instead of lumped together into a string. One of the things that become problematic is ordering, another is filtering, without it having very poor performance. You will need to break apart the string for ordering.

Comment: Thanks Lasse, but for several reasons I can't change the DB structure now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data field is varchar  "`Week xx [xxxx]`" just like you say in the comment, so you can try using this query:

```
select * from your_table order by substring(your_field,10,4) desc, substring(your_field,6,2) desc
```

For example, you can see in this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3418c/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

Try IComparable with Regex :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication152
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] input = { "Week 02 [2020]", "Week 03 [2020]", "Week 36 [2019]", "Week 40 [2019]", "Week 47 [2019]", "Week 52 [2019]" };

            string[] output = input.Select(x => new Date(x)).OrderByDescending(x => x).Select(x => x.text).ToArray();
        }
    }
    public class Date : IComparable<Date>
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
        public int week { get; set; }
        public int year { get; set; }

        const string pattern = @"Week\s+(?'week'\d+)\s+\[(?'year'\d+)\]";

        public Date(string text)
        {
            this.text = text;
            Match match = Regex.Match(text,pattern);
            week = int.Parse(match.Groups["week"].Value);
            year = int.Parse(match.Groups["year"].Value);
        }

        public int CompareTo(Date other)
        {
            // If other is not a valid object reference, this instance is greater.
            if (this.year != other.year)
            {
                return this.year.CompareTo(other.year);
            }
            else
            {
                return this.week.CompareTo(other.week);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but it is returning in ascending order by week only...

Comment: Are you using the linq statement in my code?  Is the data in the list box a string or is it a DateTime?  The code posted works properly when the input is a string. Maybe they are tabs or more spaces in your code the what I used?  I changed the patter to use \s+ to be more robust.  Are you replacing the existing values with the output of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Solution that comes to my mind at first:

Store your weeks in database in multiple columns; one column for week number, one for year, and more for any other data you want to save along with that particular week.

So let's consider your databse will look like this:

```
id | week | year
---+------+-----
0  | ­­ 36  | 2019
1  | ­ 03  | 2020
```

...

On this database you do

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
ORDER BY year DESC, week DESC;
```

Now you shall get result in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

Sort in memory alternative to SQL:

```
  // Get item list from your database. Hardcoded here.
var items = new List<string>{ "Week 02 [2020]", "Week 03 [2020]", "Week 36 [2019]", "Week 40 [2019]", "Week 47 [2019]", "Week 52 [2019]" };

// Sort in-memory. Assumes formats are FIXED.
items.Sort((x,y) => {
    int result = string.Compare(y.Substring(9,4), x.Substring(9,4));
    if (result == 0)
    {
         result = string.Compare(y.Substring(5,2), x.Substring(5,2));
    }
    return result;
});

// Now assign items to your listbox.

// For demo, output result of the sort
foreach (var s in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dOY7j0)

Output:

```
Week 03 [2020]
Week 02 [2020]
Week 52 [2019]
Week 47 [2019]
Week 40 [2019]
Week 36 [2019]
```